# R: Trying to analyse spending patterns of 2 genders in the same month

Tags: r

I am pretty new to R and trying to get a bar plot to represent the data below:

| Month | Gender | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| August | Male | 346 |
| August | Female | 981 |
| September | Male | 287 |
| September | Female | 238 |
| October | Male | 173 |
| October | Female | 199 |

I have tried the following:

```
gender_count <- x %>% select(date,gender) %>% mutate(month = format(x$date, "%B")) %>% group_by(month, gender) %>% count() %>%
   ggplot(aes(x=month, y=n)) +
   geom_bar(aes(group = "gender"), fill= "red", stat="identity", width = 0.2)
```

I am unable to get it by both month and gender, but instead, get one or the other.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `ggplot(df1, aes(Month, Count, fill = Gender)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())`. This is probably a duplicate.

Comment: It would help to know more about what you want the final product to look like. One option would be to add `facet_wrap(~month)` to make separate plots by month (or switch `group=month` and `facet_wrap(~gender)` to have two monthly plots).

Comment: Thanks for the replies!

I'd like to essentially have 6 bar plots of 2 different colours. So the x-label on each bar plot would be the month and the colour would refer to the gender (for which I'll add a legend).

Comment: @mikebader Thanks for your help too! Tried yours out and now I know two ways to do it!